# Как быть с пунктуацией при вставной конструкции с использованием восклицательных/вопросительных знаков?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, тире

У Розенталя есть по этому поводу следующее:

> Перед первым тире ставится запятая, если этого требует структура
> первой части основного предложения: *Он посмотрел на пепелище, которое
> окружало его, — какой ужас! — и руки бессильно опустились у него* —
> запятая закрывает придаточную часть сложноподчиненного предложения.

Как быть с запятой, которая предполагается между частями предложения на месте восклицательного знака, если убрать придаточную часть?
"Он посмотрел на пепелище (,) — какой ужас! — и руки бессильно опустились у него". Мне кажется, запятая перед первым тире в таком случае нужна, так как восклицательный знак делает невозможным постановку знака препинания в необходимом месте; вместе с тем отсутствие запятой выглядит странно. Мне кажется, что запятую надо поставить перед первым тире. Так ли?

Мой вопрос не является дубликатом, так как повторяется лишь приведенный пример, однако суть заданного отличается от вопроса с таким же примером, взятым у Розенталя. Это не дубликат, потому что ответа на мой вопрос там нет.

Comment: http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=123

Comment: Я не вижу там ответа на мой вопрос. Прочитайте, что я спрашиваю и что спрашивает человек из "дубликата". Где в дубликате ответ на вопрос, как быть с запятой без придаточной части в ССП с использованием конструкций, в которых присутствует восклицательный/вопросительный знак на месте необходимой запятой?

Answer (score 1):

> Как быть с запятой, которая предполагается между частями предложения
> на месте восклицательного знака, если убрать придаточную часть? "Он
> посмотрел на пепелище (,) — какой ужас! — и руки бессильно опустились
> у него".

А где тут "придаточная часть"? Вы говорите о "которое окружало его"?

Или спрашиваете про вставную конструкцию ("какой ужас!")?

Если поочерёдно изъять одно и другое, останется:

1. *Он посмотрел на пепелище — какой ужас! — и руки бессильно опустились у него.*
2. *Он посмотрел на пепелище, которое окружало его, и руки бессильно опустились у него.*

Разумеется, в первом случае запятая отменяется: предложение становится сложносочинённым и две его самодостаточные части разъединяет восклицательный знак.